# Is God a permanent fixed identity or is he evolving?

Tags: theology

God is often considered to be a fixed idea or identity. God is most loving and kind in the treatment of his subjects. However that can not always be true because we are evolving. As we are evolving we are changing and God must change his ways of handling us over period of time. For example  if we become evil then God must adjust his philosophy to bring us back on the track of good will and love. 
Therefore my question is : Is God a permanent fixed identity or is he evolving along with us?

Comment: Maybe you’d find something like [process theology](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/process-theism/) and its analogues helpful for thinking this through.

Comment: Which god are you talking about? There are at [approximately 4200 religions groups](http://atheism.wikia.com/wiki/How_many_gods%3F) in operation on Earth today. Some of those are polytheistic. This puts the number of gods into the **thousands**. So... which one of those thousands are you talking about? And once you have found that out: [Christianity SE](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/), [Hinduism SE](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/), [Buddhism SE](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/), [Islam SE](https://islam.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Any God. But we can take the Christian God for example.

Comment: That question is better suited on [Christianity.se] or similar, but be sure to read their help center first.

Comment: The polytheistic believers are not devoid of personal attention from their chosen God. For example there 3 main Gods in Hinduism , Brahma ,Vishnu and Mahesh or Shiva. But when it comes to taking care , every God personally attends to his followers.

Comment: @DheerajVerma Then put the question on [Christianity Stack Exchange](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/). Also note that god(s) do not share **all** attributes between religions.

Comment: @MichaelK I am surprised theology doesnt even know what is God and what are the properties of God. Theology seems to have lost itself in the diversity of Gods and philosophies.

Comment: @DheerajVerma **A** god can have any number of qualities. There are **thousands** of gods being worshipped, they are not all alike. So to ask about **gods in general** makes no sense, especially if you have not nailed down what a god should actually be defined as. If you want to ask about the qualities of a **particular** god, then that question is bet suited on a Stack Exchange themed around the religion that worships that particular god.

Comment: Some people claim that he has evolved to become a she.

Comment: @Bram28 God transcends gender. I used he for convenience.

Comment: The concept of *God* is an human creation. Mankind is evolving (i.e. changing). Therefore: the idea of God is evolving (i.e. changing) along with us.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I agree with you. God must be evolving along with us. But I think God is not just a concept. God has been like a Father taking care of his children. Children are evolving so is the Father.

Comment: The idea of evolving God (Absolute) is [associated with Hegel](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/hegel/#TraMetVieHeg). In more traditional accounts subjecting God to time and change was seen as demeaning his absoluteness. The problem with the question as currently phrased is that it invites personal opinions on the matter, please make it more objectively answerable e.g. by focusing on  arguments for or against a position.

Comment: @Mauro Allegranza, I am thinking your argument is unsound. Can you clarify your premises? As written you argument is not in standard form & you are hidding a premise. I can see how to place the argument in a valid form but this is not enough.

Comment: Actually evolution is not a change of object. It is change of species through generations. Since god is thought as single one (whatever god you would consider, even Zeus) tem "evolve" is not proper. "Change", for sure is proper.

Comment: @rus9384 are you changing randomly or are you evolving ?

Comment: Well, evolution is just adaptation to natural conditions through *generations*. It is possible that evolution could make some species less intelligent or weaker, etc. What you mean is development, I'd say.

Answer (score 2):

Samuel Alexander (1859-1938) presents a view of God as as an evolving being within the universe. God has an existence now but a potential existence which will evolve into fulness. This view is presented in Space, Time and Deity (1920). A flavour of his approach to God is given in this extract:

> His view of deity is unique. It is defined in terms of the principle of emergence, according to which nature rises to successively higher and superimposed levels. Although the human mind is thus far pre-eminent, the principle of emergence implies higher levels beyond, which will be related to the human mind as this, in turn, is related to body. Deity is this prospective superiority viewed from below, and God is the supreme eminence or infinite being, viewed with reverent expectancy by man. (John K. McCreary, 'The Religious Philosophy of Samuel Alexander', The Journal of Religion, Vol. 27, No. 2 (Apr., 1947), 111.

Alexander's views are complex and hard to summarise clearly in a short space but, to judge by the terms of your question, he might be a figure worth exploring.

Comment: If God is evolving along with us then God is no fixed entity.

Answer (score 1):

Although the dominant Western conception of God is as having a perfection that cannot admit change, there do exist philosophers, [such as Hegel](https://philosophynow.org/issues/86/Hegels_God), who have an evolutionary view of God.

However, it is not necessary that God change in order to explain an evolving relationship with people as they evolve. As we drive down the highway, we may see what looks to us like a mountain that is changing.  But the mountain is not changing, it is just that its position *relative to us* is changing, and therefore we are getting many different evolving perspectives on it.

This especially makes sense if we grant that our conception of God is (probably/necessarily) limited in relationship to the totality of God's actuality.  Just as we see a mountain that changes, when it is really us changing, our perceptions and conceptions of God may change as we evolve, but that does not necessitate that God is actually changing.

Comment: "This is less a function of the mother changing" - don't you say that mother is not changing? She gets new memories and memories are part of mind. Since of that she is changing through getting new memories.

Comment: @rus9384 It's not a perfect metaphor, your mother isn't actually God.

Comment: Mother is changing but not for herself but for her children. As the children are growing she needs to adjust her philosophy to take care of them. But it is also true that mother is a mother. In many ways the mother is same as the old mother and in many ways mother is different from the old mother. But there is no permanent ,unchanging Mother ,similarly there is no permanent , unchanging God.

Comment: Actually, this just makes me think that people do not have clear definition of "change". We view "changing" as different processes.

Comment: @DheerajVerma I changed the metaphor, since it seems to not be doing the work I hoped it would.

Answer (score 1):

> I am **the LORD**, I **change not**... (Malachi 3:6, KJV)
>
> **But we** all, with open face beholding as in a glass the glory of the Lord, **are changed** into the same image from glory to glory, even as by the Spirit of the Lord. (Corinthians 3:18, KJV)

Change is relative, by the way. The French say it best:

> In 1839 [Jean-Baptiste] Alphonse Karr became editor of *Le Figaro*, to which he had been a constant contributor; and he also started a monthly journal, *Les Guêpes*, of a keenly satirical tone, a publication which brought him the reputation of a somewhat bitter wit. His epigrams are frequently quoted, for example **plus ça change, plus c'est la même chose** — "the more it changes, the more it's the same thing", usually translated as "the more things change, the more they stay the same," (*Les Guêpes*, January 1849). On the proposal to abolish capital punishment, **je veux bien que messieurs les assassins commencent** — "let the gentlemen who do the murders take the first step". (*Wikipedia*)

Answer (score 0):

We are here on a philosophical and not a religious forum.

Before we can approach the question, whether God evolves, we have to agree that God exists and we have to find consense about some of his characteristic properties.

This agreement has not been established up to now.

Comment: Isn't this more of a comment than an answer?

Comment: Discussing specific answers to the question stated above suggests that we already know that God exists. My answer should emphasize: At present time we cannot answer the question on a sound basis.

Comment: That sounds like a comment + a close vote.

Answer (score 0):

You make an argument that is not well formed as written.  It is more on the fallacious side as written but there are still issues with terms such as God.
   God usually refers to a being that has the following attributes: all knowing, all powerful, ever present, incapable of sin, perfect, etc. Nothing else besides those qualities is worth worshipping that type of being won't have the ability to even grant some prayers you may ask.  You pray to be cured of cancer and the being reports that it doesn't even have the power to cure cancer but still wants you to worship?  At least this wannabe super hero has a sense of humor.
   In all seriousness, the concept of PERFECT does not coexist with the concept  of evolving.  If something is perfect, there is no need to change or upgrade. It makes no sense to say my life is PERFECT but I want to change z in my life. This is self contradictory. Clearly there would be nothing to change if things were perfect. There is no higher concept than perfection. Perfection expresses the idea that mistakes and errors are impossible to commit for that being. A perfect being can create less than perfect things.  Perfect means IT does not make mistakes --- NOT that you are also perfect because you were created by a perfect being. There are reasons to make things less than perfect. Perhaps that bothers you. Because of the PERFECT concept that goes along with God necessarily, the idea of God being fixed logically follows.

Answer (score 0):

This may be viewed from two different points: [Theism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theism) and [Deism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deism).

---

**Theism.**

According to wikipedia, theism is

> a belief in God or in gods without the rejection of revelation as is characteristic of deism.

Thus, theism posits that god[s] is/are affecting our world by their actions.

We may consider that those actions are not responces to what is happening in our world. In other words, those actions are independent on our world. This means that either god[s] is/are deterministic or all their actions in our world are occasional.

If we accept that those actions are responces to what is happening in our world, we must accept that these actions are parts of interactions between our world and god[s].

---

**Deism.**

According to wikipedia, in deism

> God... does not interfere directly with the created world.

While there is no interference that still does not mean god[s] is/are not watching what happens in our world. Of course, even just watching in our world is interference in our world but our physical laws might not apply outside of universe. But escape god[s]' changing in deism is much simpler. We might even consider god[s] no more exist[s].

---

The analogy from real life:

Let's say you have simulated a world in the computer. If you are tracking what happens there it already is changing you. Because that generates new memories in you thus changing your mind. If you're just watching, it is interaction in our world, but as I said may be not the case outside of it. Conscious changes indeed require some kind of tracking thus if you are consciously changing that world, you (as mind) are changing.

And many faiths (probably all) declare that god[s] is/are conscious.

---

Why just watching for simulated world is interference in our world? Because photons projected from screen can be reflected and (almost neglibly, but still it's not zero interference) affect the computer. Whether such analogy makes sense is another question. And I'd say this question can not be answered from position of knowledge.

Comment: Your analogy falls short in the case the programer knows all outcomes of the game without causing those outcomes. I am uncertain how only watching is interference. You have not made that Crystal clear.  God allegedly knows everything so you don't cover this alternative. In the bible God sometimes does directly interfere but this is only on the behalf of his chosen usually. God does not intervene for the most part. As a result of God knowing all some say free will is only  an illusion. You don't address this option either.